# How to Redrive DLQ messages to EventBridge? And what are the best Practices to reprocess/redrive DLQ messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless, aws-event-bridge

I have two main topics about DLQ I'd like to understand.

#### 1) AWS EventBridge + DLQ, how to redrive messages to EventBridge?

In a scenario where I have an EventBridge rule sending an event to an API Destination when it fails to deliver the event, it will send the event to a DLQ.

- EventBridge failed to deliver some messages to the API Destination. I get some DLQ messages. After analysis we determine the messages are good - we just had a bug in our code and should reprocess the failed events.
- Fixed the bug and deploy the changes.
- What do we do here? Is there some way to tell the event bridge to emit certain messages again? Can it only send it to certain consumers instead of all? Can we redrive the DLQ message direct to EventBridge?  I'm really confused about what to do in this part here.

#### 2) What are the best practices to reprocess DLQ messages?

- Use a Lambda? (Make the DLQ Trigger a Lambda and reprocess it?)
- Use redrive policy? And if the Message on the DLQ was generated by another resource? (We have multiple services that accept SQS as DLQ)
- Manually look to messages/use some CLI commands? (I really don't like it)
- Other methods? (I'd appreciate more information about other methods and why use them instead of the listed options)

So far I did some manual redrive and I'm trying to understand if it's worth use lambda, keeping it manually, using redrive or is there are other and better options.

(Please let me know if I missed any detail here, thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked automatic DLQ redrive feature only worked for SQS -> DLQ scenario, so won’t work in your case. I can suggest couple of options:

1. If you can make your target idempotent (which you should do anyway, because eventbridge does not guarantee only-once delivery), then you can use EventBridge Archive to [replay events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-replay-archived-event.html). This feature also support replaying only specific rules, so you can limit replay to a single destination.
2. You can write a custom script that will read messages from DLQ and invoke your destination for each message. Not ideal, but not too complicated either.